# From blender to unreal smoothgroup and shading

Tags: texturing, normals, unreal-engine

I have an issue with building a low poly model for Unreal.
There is the picture of the model in Substance Designer
[image: Substance Designer preview almost perfect]

The same model in Marmoset

[image: Marmoset viewport, some weird crosses are there]

You can see there are some weird crosses all over the model.
The same crosses are in Unreal

The model very simple and I'll be happy to keep it simple. Here is a Blender view
[image: Blender View] 
What do you think how can I fix those issues? It is obviously because of smoothgrouping but why then it works in Substance?

Comment: You should edit the headline of the question to somthing ellse that is specific for this problem like Shading problems, unreal export.

Comment: Yes, that defines the issue better.

Comment: Are the faces planar? (all vertices laying on the same imaginary plane) It's most likely not related to format used for exporting, it's about triangulation of the mesh faces visible in real time rendering programs or if rendering e.g. in Blender

Comment: Yes, Thank you. It is, after using triangulation before export the issue has gone. Though it is a bit strange that it wasn't mentioned anywhere in the internet lessons.

Answer (score 0):

You can uneversaly try to export a .obj if you only whant a mesh. In the settings you will find a addon tab that have a unreal import-export feture disable in 2.79 (.psk/.psa)

The problem is usaly that the export are missing information or is procesed diffrent and you will need to deal with it in the other program

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it. I've got an advice from a friend of mine, he said that is because of triangulation, different programs does it in a different way. That is why in a program where I bake it looks ok. I triangulate it before export and now it looks fine everywhere. What to do if you need to keep polygons square i don't know