# How to enable auto smooth option for unreal engine?

Tags: modeling, export, normals, unreal-engine

When i export my object into ue4 it looks awful without auto smooth option
I see auto smooth is disabled in unreal engine. Is this possible to enable auto smooth for unreal engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Click here if you have the same problem.
https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/1630503-how-to-enable-auto-smooth-option-for-unreal-engine-need-immediately-help-please

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the Smoothing to Face under Geometry when you export FBX.

[image]

Comment: not this. İt's only for smoothing. İt doesn't includes auto smooth. Already tried this way

Comment: Then it's something on the import settings in unreal that is missing.

Comment: already checked :( still no solution.

Comment: Strange... it works for me every single time.

Comment: no no no it works! But it doesnt takes the auto smooth which under Normals tab.

Comment: can you show me please ??

Comment: @trolltime lol...

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid what the ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i got a couple of solutions for that because i had the same problem, and it was really hard information about it and i want to contribute with more people using blender. So here we go. (this are aproaches for ue4 from diferent people)

Option 1. Generated Smoothing and TSpaces in Blender

In exporting settings in Geometry Tab set Smoothing to >> Face and select Tangent Spaces. Important method for this object must be Ngons free and have clean uv’s. When importing in Unreal Engine 4, select Normal Import Method to >> Import Normals and Tangents. This method let you keep Blender smoothing with calculated normals and hard edges.

Source https://www.multipainkiller-studio.one/dev-tips/export-settings-from-blender-3d-to-unreal-engine-4/

Option 2. Triangulate Before export

.."because of triangulation, different programs does it in a different way. That is why in a program where I bake it looks ok. I triangulate it before export and now it looks fine everywhere".

Source [From blender to unreal smoothgroup and shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95627/from-blender-to-unreal-smoothgroup-and-shading)

Option 3. Mark edges Sharp (not so sure about this one but may work for someone)

Make sure auto smooth is set off, just use normal smooth, and that there are no modifiers on the mesh. Now with sharp edges of your model marked sharp, export the fbx with smoothing set to edge.

Source https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/26005-blender-same-model-but-different-shading-quality

Option 4. With Auto Smooth

Mark Sharp edges with auto smooth enabled in the normals section of the object. Set the smooth angle to be 180°, and when exporting set to "normals only".

Option 5. Importing From Unreal

If you are importing from blender to unreal, and get the degenerate tangent base problem check this

[Blender weird shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70688/blender-weird-shading)
..

(cant upload images right now, but i´ll hope to improve the answer later. Sorry if broke any rule, and of course that my english it´s not the best)

Answer (score 0):

or you can also use edge split modifier on your object and export it